# Pymongo update/upsert with dictionary

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, pymongo, upsert

I have a dictionary of data that looks for example like this:

```
dict = [{'name': 'test', 'domain': 'www.example.com', 'rawdata':'dbe318e7'},
{'name': 'test2', 'domain': 'www.example.com', 'rawdata':'dbe318e8'},
{'name': 'test3', 'domain': 'www.example.com', 'rawdata':'dbe318e8'}]
```

I want to do an upsert into mongodb using pymongo where 'rawdata' should be unique and I have it working with this:

```
for x in dict:
            myColl.update({'rawdata': x['rawdata']}, x, True)
```

But is this the best way to do it or is there a simpler upsert without looping on the dictionary?

Comment: A list comprehension is for filtering a sequence of data but not for calling arbitrary code replacing a standard for loop. Misuse of a Python feature!

Comment: Updated my question esaelPsnoroMoN to use a proper loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other way since you need distinct search criteria for each item of the dict. So the answer is no - which is not different from the behavior of a RDBMS.